# How do i get a list of all currently connected clients to my server in netty?

Tags: java, netty

In my application clients are communicating via Websockets. So i want to know how many clients(browser) are connected to my Netty server. I want to maintain a list of all active clients by adding them in the order they join and remove any client who disconnects from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the channelActive(...) method and add the Channel to the list. Remove it again on the channelInactive(...) method. This methods exists in ChannelInboundHandler.